# Where can I find the number of commercial jets that a country or airline purchases annually?

Tags: commercial-aviation, aircraft-purchase

Is there any authoritative source from where we can find out the number of commercial jets that a country or airline purchases annually?

Comment: Do you want to count options as well?

Comment: Wikipedia mentions is for many airlines and for manufacturers too.

Comment: @ Burhan Khalid - I can take the option factor into account as well.  @ Farhan - Wikipedia does not mention for every airline

Answer (score 3):

[planespotters.net](https://www.planespotters.net/) lists, for many commercial airlines, all their airplanes along with their delivery dates.

As for an *authoritative source*, you would have to look at the IATA or any other paying site such as airfleets.net.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia lists are nice, but think about this question backwards to get the **authoritative source**. Find and parse the manufacturer data on the exact number of airliners sold.

Examples:

- [Airbus](http://www.airbus.com/company/market/orders-deliveries/) (or [direct link](http://www.airbus.com/company/market/orders-deliveries/?eID=maglisting_push&tx_maglisting_pi1%5BdocID%5D=67284) to the spreadsheet download on that page)
- [Boeing](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/#/orders-deliveries) (lots of nice filtering options!)

You could search for older reports or archives of previous years.